# Why does Jmeter's JMS Publisher generate NameNotFoundException for ConnectionFactory?

Tags: jmeter, jms, ibm-mq, jndi

I'm trying to publish a message to an **IBM MQ** queue using **Jmeter's JMS Publisher**, but when i run the test, the JMS Publisher fails and it returns the following error.

**IBM MQ 9.3.2.0**

[NameNotFoundException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDHvd.png)

Here's the publisher configuration and the .bindings file i used to define the ConnectionFactory.

[JMS Publisher Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAVZi.png)

```
ConnectionFactory/ClassName=javax.jms.ConnectionFactory
ConnectionFactory/FactoryName=com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactoryFactory
ConnectionFactory/RefAddr/0/Content=QM1
ConnectionFactory/RefAddr/0/Type=queueManager
ConnectionFactory/RefAddr/1/Content=127.0.0.1
ConnectionFactory/RefAddr/1/Type=host
ConnectionFactory/RefAddr/2/Content=1414
ConnectionFactory/RefAddr/2/Type=port
ConnectionFactory/RefAddr/3/Content=DEV.APP.SVRCONN
ConnectionFactory/RefAddr/3/Type=channel
ConnectionFactory/RefAddr/4/Content=SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN
ConnectionFactory/RefAddr/4/Type=transportType
MyTestQueue/ClassName=com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue
MyTestQueue/FactoryName=com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueFactory
MyTestQueue/RefAddr/0/Content=DEV.QUEUE.1
MyTestQueue/RefAddr/0/Type=name
MyTestQueue/RefAddr/1/Content=queue:///DEV.QUEUE.1
MyTestQueue/RefAddr/1/Type=address
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#lets_start):

> JMeter includes the JMS API jar, but does not include a JMS client implementation. If you want to run JMS tests, **you will need to download the appropriate jars from the JMS provider**.
>
> See the [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) section for details on installing additional jars.

So you need to have the appropriate version of [com.ibm.mq.allclient](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.mq/com.ibm.mq.allclient) library in "lib" folder of your JMeter installation.

And the connection factory should be `com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsConnectionFactory`

More information: [IBM MQ Tutorial: Learn How to Testing With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-tutorial)

Comment: I already have the com.ibm.mq.allclient, javax.jms-api and fscontext jars in the "lib" folder, and as for the the connection factory, i changed it the .bindings file and i still get the same exception, i also tried changing it the JMS Publisher's config but i'm still getting the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

You have not described how you created your .bindings file, obviously not with JMSAdmin.
Create two files in a config directory of your choice:

1. JMSAdmin.config (template available in *mq-install-dir*\java\bin):

```
INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY=com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory
PROVIDER_URL=file:///C:/Users/Stage/Downloads/JNDI-Directory
SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION=none
```

2. whatever.scp:

```
def qcf(ConnectionFactory) qmanager(QM1) transport(client) channel(DEV.APP.SVRCONN) hostname(127.0.0.1) port(1414)
def q(MyTestQueue) queue(DEV.QUEUE.1)
end
```

Because your Queue Manager is local to JMeter, you could also use local bindings (no network) and define the qcf like this:

```
def qcf(ConnectionFactory) qmanager(QM1)
```

All parameters are described in the MQ documentation in chapter "Properties of IBM MQ classes for JMS objects".

Remove your .bindings file in the target jndi directory and then execute:

```
"<mq-install-dir>\java\bin\JMSAdmin" < whatever.scp
```

like

```
"C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\bin\JMSAdmin" < whatever.scp
```

You will find .bindings in the directory specified in the config file.
For subsequent invocations either remove .bindings before, or use alter commands instead of define's in your scp file.